# Cant "Hello World" in Mirah programming language

Tags: jruby, mirah

I'm a Computer Science student, and in one of the courses every student gets his own programming language to use through the entire course.
I got Mirah programming language.
The thing is, I followed this link: https://github.com/mirah/mirah/wiki/Getting-Started
I installed Mirah succesfully using "gem install mirah", but I can't execute the inline script:
mirah -e 'puts "Hello, Mirah!"'
When I try, I get the following error: No such file Mirah!

I'm using Windows 10.

BTW, if there are any IDEs I can use to program in Mirah with, that would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know anything about Mirah but I would suggest installing Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10 and try running your command from within that environment.

Comment: Is 'mirah' added to PATH variable in your system environment?

Comment: @rajan_saini.98 I tried. can you tell me if I did this right?
view advanced system settings -> environment variables 
and then, under "system variables", I clicked "path", and then "edit", and added the path to mirah, which i located in "C:\jruby-9.1.17.0\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\mirah-0.2.1-java\bin"

Comment: @Elyasaf755 yes you did it right. If the problem still persists, try reinstalling

Comment: Give a try to Windows Powershell.

Comment: I tried. Didnt worked. I also tried opening powershell from the bin folder, didnt work either